# Possible to use laptop with 1920 max resolution with 4k monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have an older (2018ish) Lenovo laptop which has both Intel HD Graphics 530 and Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M graphics and I recently received a new 4k monitor for work.

I have connected the laptop to the monitor using an HDMI cable and would like to bump up the resolution from 1920x1080 higher so that I have more screen real estate on the new 4k monitor - currently the screen is really zoomed in :(.

Is there any way for me to do this using my graphics options?

I tried using the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel to create a custom resolution for the monitor but I am getting an error when saving the custom resolution "The custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity". Is there anything else I can do to increase the resolution?

I've read lots of posts talking about muxers and different types of HDMI cables but I can't figure out if I should even try to go down that route or if with my setup higher resolution just isn't supported.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What revision of HDMI are you using?  Both the Intel HD Graphics 530 and GTX 950M should have the capability to output 4K but the HDMI revision being used is important.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the frame rate? if 60 Hz is too fast (high bandwidth), 30 Hz might work, albeit with possible flicker.

Comment: Have you tried downloading NVIDIA Control App from the Microsoft store and adding a custom resolution through that instead? Echoing what Dmitry said in his answer, you want to go to your Windows display settings, scroll down and select "Extend these displays". This will allow you to independently change the resolution of each monitor.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine in 4K (but may be just 30Hz depending on what GPU HDMI is actually connected to and sometimes the cable used).

One important thing to note is: if you use "duplicate screens" mode when using 2 monitors on Windows, then you can only select the same resolution on both monitors. If it is your case, try the "expand" mode and see if it works

Comment: Indeed. It should be added that when mirroring the same resolution must match the lower one.